# Connect to Apple Time Capsule on 22.04 - NTLM V1

Tags: 22.04, samba, apple

I have not been successful in connecting to my apple time capsule samba share in Ubuntu 22.04. Here is my command:

sudo mount.cifs //TimeCapsuleIPAddress/Data /media/timecapsule -o vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,uid=$USER,pass=mypassword

This gives me the error: mount error(22): Invalid argument

If I remove "sec=ntlm" or change it to "sec=ntlmv2", I get: mount error(13): Permission denied.

So it seems that not being able to use ntlm is my issue. I found this link:
https://blog.mondoo.com/new-security-features-in-ubuntu-22.04-server
which states that in 22.04: "The CIFS filesystem module no longer supports the weak LANMAN and NTLM protocols used by SMBv1."

Does this mean that there is no way to connect to my time capsule SAMBA share? Is there any way to restore NTLM v1?

UPDATE - I found an active discussion on the removal of NTLMv1 from the kernel. For now it seems the only option is to downgrade or patch the kernel.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215375

Comment: UPDATE - I found an active discussion on the removal of NTLMv1 from the kernel. For now it seems the only option is to downgrade the kernel.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215375

Comment: Hurray for updates. Hurray for Linux for keeping our older machines in operation (not). Thank you for the link to the discussion.
I would be happy with some workaround, having a docker container to deal with the connection and provide with a finder/explorer to let me interact with the files on the Apple Time Capsule, I fixed one a year ago replacing the hard disk so it can serve me for the next years again only to find this 'Kernel upgrade'. 
As an alternative it should be possible to have NTLMv1 installed if you as a user decide you want/need to use that. I think my usecase makes sense.

Comment: I think it is hard to imagine the Linux dev's are trying to sell new hardware to me, or scare me off to return to Windows where I can access my data.
For now I go and find some time to figure out if there is any other distro around that is an option for me to use.